# how to retrieve the characters after enter special character in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

hi i am working on php with jquery. i am planing to develop post like twitter . basically i can handle php well but my doubt here regarding jquery. i want get characters after entering the '@' in characters but i am getting all characters which i entered before '@' in text area.

html code:

```
<span>Comment:</span><textarea   id="comment" name="comment"> </textarea>
```

jquery code:

```
     $(document).ready(function (e){
$('#comment').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 50) {
            posting();

     }
  })
         });

function posting(){
        $('#comment').keydown(function(e){
      var value = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        alert(value);
        })
      }
```

while running this my output is: hai how are you @ram
but i am looking for @ram just. if any have idea please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var val = $("textarea").val();
var myString = val.substr(val.indexOf("@") + 1)

 myArray = myString.split(" ");
 alert(myArray[0]);
});
</script>

<span>Comment:</span><textarea   id="comment" name="comment">afhsjdhf sdfsdf @ram asasd</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 var val = $("textarea").val();
 var myString = val.substr(val.indexOf("@") + 1)
 alert(myString);
```

Enjoy -:)

Comment: put this inside textarea change function

Comment: @Muhamamd Usman what if two two tag names are there  like hai @ mahesh how about @ rav here i want 2nd tag name?